# Difference Xna Enum touchState

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, touchscreen

I'm working on a Windows app using XNA.

Actually I succeed moving my sprite, but I want to add a different action when the user touch the sprite but don't move it. I know `TouchlocationState` Enum [exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.touchlocationstate.aspx) but I don't understand the difference between `Moved` and `Pressed`.
For now I use `Released` and that's enough, I update the sprite position while it's not released and then I check collision.
So how can I add only one touch method when it's clicked? I mean when the user tap the sprite but don't move it.
Some code:

```
TouchPanelCapabilities touchCap = TouchPanel.GetCapabilities();
if (touchCap.IsConnected)
{
    TouchCollection touches = TouchPanel.GetState();
    if (touches.Count >= 1)
        {
        Vector2 PositionTouch = touches[0].Position;

        if (touches[0].State == TouchLocationState.Released)
        {
            // Pause button click and others buttons
            Mouseclik((int)PositionTouch.X, (int)PositionTouch.Y);       
        }

        if (!PausePopUp)
        {
            CheckMoove(PositionTouch);
            if (touches[touches.Count - 1].State == TouchLocationState.Released)
            {
            // this is where i try to add/check if its only "click" on my sprite
                    if (touches[0].Position == touches[touches.Count - 1].Postion)
                    {
                        TempoRectangle = ListSprite[save].ShapeViser;
                        isclicked = true;
                    }
```

My goal is to add a picturebox above the sprite to display information then if an other sprite is touched while the picturebox is diplayed, I want to draw a line between these 2 sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is simple:

- `TouchLocationState.Pressed` means that a new location is detected.
- `TouchLocationState.Moved` means that the location position was updated or pressed at the same position

This means that you will get only a `Pressed` state for each touch action, a sequence of `Moved` every cycle while the touch is pressed, and when you release it you'll get a `Released`.

This is explained in the link you provided, too.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I found _GestureSample_ while i was looking for information. I think I'll change all my moovement gestion with that

Comment: That could be a solution, but a little tip to you, if you need to use `FreeDrag` gesture you'd better know that the program will detect it only when you start dragging the touch, not only pressing it. Something similar happens when you use the `Hold`, it will fire only after few seconds. And the `DoubleTap` it's hard to detect.